# Header, including the first page

Tags: header-footer

I have a short existing document formatting with the `article` class. What is the best way to include a header on each page (including the first) with my name and academic affiliation? The options I have looked at do not include the first page.

Comment: It can be done, as has already been answered, but a header on the first page is not a good practice. What use could it have? Show (again on the same page) the author, but in a smaller font?. Show (again) the title or date? Find the current section, which will invariably "Introduction" in  scientific articles and in any case it will be always the first section?

Comment: @Fran, I would generally agree with you.  But if you're submitting a resume, I think it is good practice to make sure your name appears on every page.  Also, some positions request that every page of any document submitted be labeled in a particular manner.  So potato's query does have its value.

Comment: @A.Ellett  Agreed: first-page headers can be used for logos, copyright, reference, etc. Another good reason is being forced to do so, even with the author's name. But a good reason is not a good practice. If the author is already **on the same page**, in prominent place with enough font size, can be tedected at first glance. Copy this name a few lines above is useless. Otherwise, you must improve the visibility of the author instead of making it ubiquitous to compensate the bad design. Moreover, it might be considered a dowdy desire for prominence.

Comment: @fran.  I completely agree.

Comment: @Fran I agree a header on the first page is bad typography, but it is forced on me by formatting requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{TOP:LEFT}
\chead{TOP:CENTER}
\rhead{TOP:RIGHT}
\lfoot{Bottom:left}
\cfoot{Bottom:center}
\rfoot{Bottom:right}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If you want two lines in a portion of the header:

```
\rhead{\parbox[b]{1in}{My Name\newline{}TOP:RIGHT}}
```

But you'll get complaints about head height.  To get around this you can load the `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in,
            headheight=25pt,                           
            ]{geometry}
```

But make sure you load `geometry` before you load `fancyhdr` or your margins will not come out correctly.  However, as @egreg has pointed out, you needn't go so far as to load the `geometry` package. You can just write

```
 \setlength{headheight}{25pt}
```

I suggested the `geometry` package route because I usually want to change the default margins LaTeX uses and the `geometry` packages makes this much easier.

If you have a title page, after you've issued `\titlepage` add the line:

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

to get your header and footers on a page that normally wouldn't have header or footers.

Comment: Loading the `geometry` package like that will change the page parameters. All is needed is to add `\setlength{\headheight}{<dimen>}` where `<dimen>` is what reported by `fancyhdr`